# Why is Biomart giving different number of paralogues to the ensembl website?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, biomart

This is the code I am using to extract paralogues for the AA792892 gene:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("biomaRt")

library(biomaRt)

ensembl_mouse <- useMart("ensembl", 
                     dataset = "mmusculus_gene_ensembl")

AA792892_paralogues <- getBM(attributes = c("external_gene_name",
                                  "mmusculus_paralog_associated_gene_name"), 
                     filters = "external_gene_name", 
                     values = "AA792892" , mart = ensembl_mouse) 

View(AA792892_paralogues)
```

The results show that there are 99 paralogues in total, but when looking at the Ensembl website, it says that there are 100 for this gene. This is happening for quite a few genes and I cant work out why.

Link:
https://www.ensembl.org/Mus_musculus/Gene/Compara_Paralog?db=core;g=ENSMUSG00000073497;r=5:94339749-94385079

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United 
Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           

[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.4    biomaRt_2.34.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.15         AnnotationDbi_1.40.0 bindr_0.1            
magrittr_1.5         BiocGenerics_0.24.0  progress_1.1.2       
IRanges_2.12.0      
 [8] bit_1.1-12           R6_2.2.2             rlang_0.1.6          
httr_1.3.1           stringr_1.2.0        blob_1.1.0           tools_3.4.3         

[15] parallel_3.4.3       Biobase_2.38.0       DBI_0.7              
yaml_2.1.16          bit64_0.9-7          digest_0.6.15        
assertthat_0.2.0    
[22] tibble_1.4.2         bindrcpp_0.2         S4Vectors_0.16.0     
bitops_1.0-6         curl_3.1             RCurl_1.95-4.10      glue_1.2.0          

[29] memoise_1.1.0        RSQLite_2.0          stringi_1.1.6        
compiler_3.4.3       pillar_1.1.0         prettyunits_1.0.2    stats4_3.4.3        

[36] XML_3.98-1.9         pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

Comment: Maybe package and the website using different versions? Can you give other gene examples?

Comment: Try updating biomart, you are using an older version